# How to improve this programme to work master also

Tags: mpi, master-slave

In this mpi programme only works slave nodes. How to modify it to work master also. Because working of the master also improve the performance of the system.

```
int A,B,C, slaveid,recvid,root, rank,size;

MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);

MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);

/*-------------------------- master ------------------------------*/

if(rank == 0){

    N =10;  

    for(slaveid=1; slaveid<size; slaveid++){

       MPI_Send(&N, 1, MPI_INT, slaveid, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    }

    for(recvid=1; recvid<size; recvid++){
        MPI_Recv(&A, 1, MPI_INT, recvid, 2, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);

    printf(" My id = %d and i send = %d\n",recvid,A);
    }
}

/*-------------------------- Slave ------------------------------*/

if(rank>0){

    MPI_Recv(&B, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);

    C = B*3;

    MPI_Send(&C, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 2, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

}

MPI_Finalize();
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Within the block delimited by

```
if(rank == 0){

}
```

insert, at the appropriate location, the line

```
work_like_a_slave(argument1, argument2,...)
```

The appropriate location is probably between the loop that sends messages and the loop that receives messages so that the master isn't entirely idle while the slaves toil.

Whether this has a measurable impact on performance depends on a number of factors your question doesn't provide enough information on which to base a good guess; factors such as: how many slaves there are and therefore how busy the master is sending and receiving messages, how much work each process does compared with the messaging it does, *etc*.

Be prepared, if the numbers work against you, for any measurable impact to be negative, that is for pressing the master into service to actually slow down your computation.

Comment: Problem is i want to use only MPI functions to implement that. Not a fuction call.

Comment: I don't understand your comment -- you want to use MPI functions to do work on your master process ?

Comment: Yes. I mean some kind of MPI_Bcast() or other mechanism

Comment: But the MPI routines are for sending messages around.  Sure a process can send itself a message (though it's questionable that doing so makes much sense) but none of them are intended to be used for doing computation.  I remain confused by your wish to use MPI functions to implement computational activity.

Comment: "if(rank==0){

  for(i=1; i<=MAXSIZE; i++) {
   data[(i-1)]=i;
  }
 }

 MPI_Bcast(data, MAXSIZE, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

 x = MAXSIZE/size;

 law = rank*x;
 max = law+x ;

 for(i=law;i<max;i++)
  result=result+data[i];
 
 printf("My %d Result is %d\n", rank,result );

 MPI_Reduce(&result, &last, 1, MPI_INT, MPI_SUM, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);"